# How to you kill a windows form program other than using x

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How do I kill a windows form application other than clicking the x button. More specifically, I need to close the program from a menu option. I am coding this in c# 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `Application.Exit()`?  It can be called from any block of code, such as a menu option or a button click.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Close` method on your main form.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for proper exit.

Environment.Exit(0).

This will terminate the application and inform the Operating system as process completed successfully.

You can call it from menu, text click event, button event etc..

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a custom handler to your menu item's OnClick event handler:

```
(Pseudocode)
    MenuItem_CloseWindow.OnClick += new OnClickHandler(YourMethodHere)
    ....
    YourMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Close();

    }
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

All Windows Forms come with the built-in ability to close them using the System Menu.  Just press ALT + SPACE and it will show the Close option unless you have set the ControlBox property to False.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for a basic Windows Form

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

If you are using  Xaml/WPF you can use:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Note: I only added this because some people think WPF and c# are the same.